# Log4j: Custom log file for each client calling web methods

Tags: jakarta-ee, logging, log4j, glassfish-3

I have a web service running on glassfish. Each client calls methods from the web service with a unique customer id and some other parameters. I have to implement a logger, which writes all the logs into a customer specific log file. There also has to be a general logger.

Example:
Client calls web method with invalid customer id, so the logger has to write into a general.log file. When the client 123 calls a method with a valid id, all the following operations should be logged into a 123.log file.

Is this possible with log4j?

Regards

Comment: I am not aware of a sifting appender in Log4j - but then again I don't really use Log4j. I can say though that this task is readily achievable using [LogBack's `SifitngAppender`](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) or [Log4j2's `RoutingAppender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/appenders.html). I would suggest you swap your logging for [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) to provide abstraction and then choose a logging backend to suit your needs. I really wouldn't advise using a specific logging library in code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a logger name in the format `wslogger.<clientID>` and then use OS commands to grep or extract the logs for a specific ID or trace certain IDs (if known) via different appenders into different files.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Could you elaborate a bit more deeply on your valuable comment? We have good experience with logging coarsely into named loggers (e.g. "Events") and later analyze the logfile with basic linux command tools or little scripts.